# Sort multimap by count

Tags: c++, sorting, multimap

Please help me to sort multimap by the count of values.

For example,

```
multimap<char,int> mymultimap;

mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('a',100));
mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('a',101));
mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('a',111));
mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('b',200));
mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('b',211));
mymultimap.insert (pair<char,int>('c',300));
```

Should be after sorting in the following order:

```
c
b
a
```

I tried to use custom comparer like this:

```
struct comparer
{
    bool operator() (const char& first, const char& second) const
    {
        return mymultimap.count(first) < mymultimap.count(second);
    }
};
```

But I can`t define

```
multimap<char, int, comparer> mymultimap;
```

Before the `struct comparer` was defined.

Comment: Why don't you just swap round key and value? That seems logical if you effectively want to index a collection based on the value and your keys are, in any case, not unique.

Comment: Why would you want to define your multimap before defining the comparison?

Comment: @Component10 Key and value doesn`t matter, I want to sort multimap according to number of elements in each element.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Because I use multimap`s method `count` inside comparer.

Comment: Note the comparer template parameter does not sort the elements, but is used for insertion. If you change the order of insertions, let's say (b, 200) as second step, you multimap would look different (when iterating over its elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.

Unless you go ahead and create a custom structure, it would seem that you need one structure to keep trace of all the items (pairs here), and one to actually count them.

The actual choice mainly depends if the sort operation is a one-off computation or if you actually need to maintain both synchronized.

If it is a one-off computation, then just count when you need and be done with it.

If you need to maintain this order, then I would suggest reading on Boost.MultiIndex and using it as a base to develop a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The comparer has the limitation that when two things are compared, they always compare consistently. Eg: If 'a' is less than 'b', this must always be true.

In your comparer, you break this rule because adding more 'a' or 'b' to the multimap could suddenly cause the result of the comparison to change.

The multimap uses the comparer to organize how it stores its elements in memory. If two elements could compare one way and then suddenly a different way, the entire organization of the elements in the multimap would have to change. multimap isn't implemented to rearrange all of its existing content when you insert only one new element as to do so would be highly inefficient.